# Updating prior probability in light of new evidence - Does Bayes work in this specific experiment?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I was pondering about an easy experiment in the framework of bayesian statistics, and reached a point where I seem to have a misunderstanding about the situation. 
 Consider the following simple setup: 

I hand you a bag and tell you that it contains 10 marbles. They are either black or white. However I don't tell you how many black and white marbles it contains respectively. I ask you to give a first guess on the probability of pulling out a white marble, and obviously the best guess you can give with the information I presented to you is that its 50% respectively. 

I now ask you to actually pull out a single marble, look at it's color and shove it back inside the bag. Let's say it was a black one. 
Now, the question is: 
 
**What is the updated probability to pull out a black marble again or a white marble?** 

Information changes probability. And probability is a measurement of uncertainty. After the "evidence" of the first marble being black, one should be able to make a more educated guess of the probability. Conducting this experiment sufficiently often should make your guess converge to the actual probability. 
 
My take:

P(B) : Probability of pulling out a black marble 
P(W) : Probability of pulling out a white marble 
P(W|B) : Probability of pulling out a white marble under the condition that the previous marble was black. 
 
Using Bayes Theorem gives:

P(W|B) = P(B|W) * P(W) / P(B) 
Now because P(W) = P(B) we get P(W|B) = P(B|W). 
This makes complete sense of course since the situation is symmetric, but didn't get me anywhere in updating a posterior probability. 
Do you know a way I can update the probability? Is Bayesian statistics the wrong way of doing this?

Comment: The initial guess on the probability of pulling out a white marble of $50\%$ is not enough to conduct Bayesian analysis: it is a point estimate, not a prior distribution.

Comment: My prior would be on the composition of the bag, that is, on the number of black balls, not on the color of the first drawn ball.

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to maybe talk about a prior distribution instead of a discrete probability - and then compute the also continuous posterior distribution. In other words: Is there any mathematical way to solve this problem - that is, being able to compute the probability through the continuous pulling-out of marbles?

Comment: I currently think of a binomial distribution. I will try this out!

Comment: You can start with a suitable prior for the $10$ marbles: one possibility is that $0,1,2,\ldots,10$ of them are white, each with probability $\frac{1}{11}$.  Another is that each is white with probability $\frac12$, so overall the number of white balls has a $\text{Bin}(10,\frac12)$ distribution.  And there are many more possibilities.   With the first suggested prior, the probability the second marble with replacement is the same colour as the first marble is $0.7$; with the second suggested prior it is $0.55$

Comment: Oh that sounds good, thank you!
Would you agree, that in both choices of the prior - after sufficiently long pulls they would both converge to the "right" probability?